# Can't change color of org.eclipse.ui.console.IOConsoleOutputStream through setColor method

Tags: java, eclipse

Even when using the setColor(Color color) method of the IOConsoleOutputStream class, the color isn't modified when writting to this stream. Does anyone know how to properly set the stream color ? Thanks :)

Here is a sample code (maybe it doesn't work because of the way I use Device and Color, but I'm not sure):

```
MessageConsoleStream mcs = mc.newMessageStream();
Color currentClr = mcs.getColor();
RGB red = new RGB(255, 0, 0);
//Device device = currentClr.getDevice();
Device device = Display.getDefault();
Color warningColor = new Color(device, red);                    
mcs.setColor(warningColor);
mcs.println("This text should be colored in red, right? But it isn't.");
mcs.setColor(currentClr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying again, I found the solution: the setColor method changes the whole stream color including already printed text.

To print messages in different colors, an option is to create several stream, each for one color, as described in this [eclipse forum thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/477241/).